# Multi-file <iostream> error LNK2005 in VS2015 with /Za

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I observered some strange error, when I migrated my projects from VS2013. Here is simplified code of a newly created project to reproduce it:

#### `A.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

extern void foo();

int main()
{
    std::cout << "some text from main" << std::endl;
    foo();
}
```

#### `B.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "some text from foo" << std::endl;
}
```

The important thing to add is project has "Disable Language Extension" set to **Yes (/Za)**. Without this setting, it is bulding properly.

The output is a long list of following errors:

```
1>B.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static bool const std::numeric_limits<short>::is_signed" (?is_signed@?$numeric_limits@F@std@@2_NB) already defined in A.obj
1>B.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int const std::numeric_limits<short>::digits" (?digits@?$numeric_limits@F@std@@2HB) already defined in A.obj
1>B.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int const std::numeric_limits<short>::digits10" (?digits10@?$numeric_limits@F@std@@2HB) already defined in A.obj
1>B.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static bool const std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::is_signed" (?is_signed@?$numeric_limits@G@std@@2_NB) already defined in A.obj
1>B.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int const std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::digits" (?digits@?$numeric_limits@G@std@@2HB) already defined in A.obj
1>B.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int const std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::digits10" (?digits10@?$numeric_limits@G@std@@2HB) already defined in A.obj
1>B.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static bool const std::numeric_limits<char16_t>::is_signed" (?is_signed@?$numeric_limits@_S@std@@2_NB) already defined in A.obj
1>B.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int const std::numeric_limits<char16_t>::digits" (?digits@?$numeric_limits@_S@std@@2HB) already defined in A.obj
...
```

This seems to indicate, that VS implementation of `<iostream>` header breaks *One Definition Rule* in some nasty way. Is it right, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Use of the /Za option is essentially unsupported and not tested by MS (since several compiler versions). Read Stephan's comments on this MS blog entry [STL fixes in VS 2015](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/07/14/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-part-2.aspx)

Comment: @BoPersson: Thanks for the reading. However, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) documentation, the `/Za` is documented and it's not deprecated in VS2015. The haven't mention anything like "don't use it". It says `Disable language extensions if you plan to port your program to other environments.`.

Comment: If you read the comments by Stephan T Lavavej - who supports the standard library at MS - he says "I stopped testing the STL with /Za years ago, ...". He has said that before in earlier blog entries.

Comment: @BoPersson: Fair enough, but still, it is not officially documented, that some of C++ standard library may not work with it. This also complicates ensuring portable, ISO-based code, that can be reused with other compilers, such as `gcc` or `clang`.

Comment: Hmya, how come a *static* declaration has external linkage?  Okay, I give up, use connect.microsoft.com to report bugs.

Comment: @HansPassant: No idea, I have submitted it already [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1625910/error-lnk2005-for-multi-file-project-that-includes-iostream-in-vs2015).

Comment: I don't see this error building in a new project (for a DLL). Either the problem is fixed in my version (Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2) or there is another option interfering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem compiling the Apache Xerces3 C++ code. The solution was already mentioned by the comment from [Stein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106275/stein). You will need an update for the Visual Studio. Version 14.0.2541.03 Update 3 worked, where my older version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1 produced the error.